# Hibernate search: persist causes sometimes OverlappingFileLockException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a WebAppilcation runnig with JPA (Hibernate 5.0.11.Final) and Hibernate Search (5.5.5.Final) in which the user tries to save a new entity. Therefor there will be serveral calls like:

```
protected Object saveNewEntity(Object toSave) {
   if (factory == null) {
       factory = Persistence
          .createEntityManagerFactory(DBBase.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
   }
   EntityManager em = initEntityManager();
   try {
       em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
       EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
       transaction.begin();
       em.persist(toSave);
       transaction.commit();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       throw e;
   } finally {
       finalizeEntityManager(em);
   }
   return toSave;
}

protected void finalizeEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
   if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
      em.close();
   }
}
```

The entity which is indexed also saved this way. It has no Cascading and is completly flat (no other tables involved).

Most of the time this will run fine and the index will be updatet.

But sometimes, I don't know why, the follwing exception will occur and therefor the index will not be updated:

```
2017-04-04 10:30:48,552 ERROR [LuceneBackendQueueTask:run:54] HSEARCH000073: Error in backend
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1108) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:114) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:775) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:123) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:89) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:80) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:162) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
2017-04-04 10:30:48,555 ERROR [LogErrorHandler:handleException:67] HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
Primary Failure:
    Entity com.rhenus.de.cm.essentials.entities.ContractSearchEntity  Id 96926  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork

java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1108) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:114) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:775) ~[lucene-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:38:09]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:123) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:89) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriterDelegate(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:198) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:80) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:46) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:162) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:148) [hibernate-search-engine-5.5.5.Final.jar:5.5.5.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
```

I do not manually lock or update the index, nor is the index used by different threads, applications or whatever.
I've read, that this can occur, if the entity has already an id and in the stacktrace the id is stated. But I definetly don't persist an entity with an id. So maybe there is a concurrency effect?

Any tips and help is appreciated. I f you need more information, just ask and I'll provide it. Thank you.

Comment: I had no further configuration in the persistence.xml, so a collegue told me, I could try:
´<property name="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy" value="none" />
 <property name="org.hibernate.search.store.LockFactoryProvider" value="org.apache.lucene.store.​NoLockFactory" /> 
I will come back and report, if this helped. Since the error is not provocable, this could take a while.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually not in Hibernate Search but in the first three lines of code.

You stated that "nor is the index used by different threads, applications or whatever", yet you also suggest this is a Web Application so it most likely needs to react to events out of your control, possibly concurrently even if you didn't expect that.

What is guaranteeing that those initial lines of code are not invoked concurrently? The initialization of the `EntityManagerFactory` might be triggered multiple times, yet there is no code shutting down the copies which have already been started.

In practice you are having multiple copies of Hibernate Search running and fighting to obtain the exclusive index lock.

Let me recommend to never disable the locking mechanism: it's designed to protect you from similar mistakes. It's enabled by default for very good reasons.

I would also suggest to use some standard approach to initialise Hibernate and/or JPA, any popular JavaEE container (like [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/)) or framework is likely to "do it right", and some of the most advanced ones can automatically enable some insane optimisations.