# Lucene indexer works on Windows, fails on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, lucene, hibernate-search

I have java application running on Jetty 9.2. Both use the same version of Jetty. The indexer runs the first time the application starts after deploying. I havent had any issues on my Windows 10 dev box in Netbeans. It does not work when i put it on a linux machine, which i only have SSH access and limited rights.

java code, Class Person runs first, class Organization runs second. both in the same hibernate session

```
public static void reindexViaMassIndexer(Class<?> type, SessionFactory factory) {
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    MassIndexerProgressMonitor monitor = new SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor();

    try {
        fullTextSession
                .createIndexer(type)
                .typesToIndexInParallel(1)
                .batchSizeToLoadObjects(BATCH_SIZE)
                .cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)
                .threadsToLoadObjects(10)
                .idFetchSize(BATCH_SIZE)
                .progressMonitor(monitor)
                .startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HibernateLuceneIndexer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

error output

```
17:48:00,188 ERROR LogErrorHandler:67 - HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/tmp/cyberdex_files/org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Organization/write.lock: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
Primary Failure:
    Entity org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Organization  Id null  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.PurgeAllLuceneWork

org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/tmp/cyberdex_files/org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Organization/write.lock: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:89)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.createNewIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.IndexWriterHolder.getIndexWriter(IndexWriterHolder.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.AbstractWorkspaceImpl.getIndexWriter(AbstractWorkspaceImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.applyUpdates(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.LuceneBackendQueueTask.run(LuceneBackendQueueTask.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.applyChangesets(SyncWorkProcessor.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.lucene.SyncWorkProcessor$Consumer.run(SyncWorkProcessor.java:135)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1108)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1155)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:169)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:96)
    ... 9 more
```

person index successful, organization failed. Note the parent directory is also jetty:jetty (user:group).

```
[jetty@server org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Person]$ ls -l
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  1844 Oct 20 18:43 _9.fdt
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty    67 Oct 20 18:43 _9.fdx
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  1310 Oct 20 18:43 _9.fnm
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  3687 Oct 20 18:43 _9_Lucene41_0.doc
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  4310 Oct 20 18:43 _9_Lucene41_0.pos
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty 20500 Oct 20 18:43 _9_Lucene41_0.tim
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty   576 Oct 20 18:43 _9_Lucene41_0.tip
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  1530 Oct 20 18:43 _9.nvd
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty   171 Oct 20 18:43 _9.nvm
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty   386 Oct 20 18:43 _9.si
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty   102 Oct 20 18:43 segments_a
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty    36 Oct 20 18:43 segments.gen
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty     0 Oct 20 14:31 write.lock
[jetty@server org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Person]$ cd ../org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Organization/
[jetty@server org.vtarc.CyberConnections.backend.entity.Organization]$ ls -l
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty 53 Oct 20 15:40 segments_5
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty 36 Oct 20 15:40 segments.gen
-rw-r-----. 1 jetty jetty  0 Oct 20 14:31 write.lock
```

need anything else?

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is you are creating multiple SessionFactories/EntityManagerFactories for the same configuration, thus instantiating Hibernate Search multiple times and creating lock conflicts on the index files. If so, well, don't. See also [Hibernate search: persist causes sometimes OverlappingFileLockException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228607/hibernate-search-persist-causes-sometimes-overlappingfilelockexception)

Another possible explanation: this version of Hibernate Search is really old. You may be experiencing a bug that has been solved since. I know there are several bugs related to locking that have been solved, for instance this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46284827/6692043

Comment: though i do spin up a Hibernate Session in 2 places, the first happens at servlet initialized and it is closed after the indexer finishes. The second session doesn't start until the main UI initializes later. this one stays in scope.

Comment: It seems its either option number 2 or some race condition. i changed logging from info to debug and everything worked. so, more logs cause the app to run a little slower, which allows everything to happen in a successful manner. awaiting another test to see if this theory is correct.

Comment: @AFowler Note that I was talking about Session*Factory* not Session. Using several sessions in parallel should work fine, but several SessionFactories using the same indexes will not. I say "*should* work fine", because as I already mentioned this is an old version of Hibernate Search and could be buggy.